# How to compress or normalise or level audio recordings?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, python

I have an phone recording, where one person sound much MUCH louder than the other because it was recorded only on one side of the phone. The original audio I was given was in mp3 format, where only the left side of the earphone has sound (though it does 2 channels). I have saved the mp3 file in mono wav file using `pydub`.

I have read on audio compression vs. normalisation (peak and loudness) vs. sound volume levelling. However, I am still confused which way I should go for.

Actually I have tried the normalisation implemented in pydub described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492246/how-to-normalize-the-volume-of-an-audio-file-in-python-any-packages-currently-a), also tried ffmpeg `loudnorm` as well as `dynaudnorm` (I didn't add any parameters though). But the resulting audio sounds no much difference to the original one. Should I manually segment out speaker turns and then apply normalisation? But then again, should I apply norm or levelling or compression? I am guessing it's between norm and levelling. I also don't want to change the characteristics of the audio since the aim here is to preprocess the audio for downstream machine learning modelling..

Does anyone have any suggestions please? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @ K7AAY. I have added more info in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalization applies gain (or negative gain) to raise (or lower) the average level.  Compression reduces loud moments and amplifies quiet moments to reduce the differences in level, and seems more appropriate for your case.

To use it in [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) (an open source sound app available for all three major operating systems), load the audio, then select the entire audio track, or just portions if you want to limit the effect to a particular passage. Choose **Effects**, then **Compressor**.

[image: Compressor dialog box]

Once the Compressor dialog box appears, press <kbd>F1</kbd> for an explanation of what the options available will do, or [read it here](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/compressor.html). I would definitely recommend turning on Compress based on Peaks, but other settings will vary based on the characteristics of the original recording.

You can experiment with different values in that dialog box to get the least worst final result; you'll never get a perfect recording, but improvement is nearly certain.

If, as often happens, a telephone audio recording has noise or other distracting audio in a particular frequency, filtering down that frequency may also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @K7AAY! I will try it now. What about levelling? I have noticed [Descript has such feature for auto-leveling](https://help.descript.com/en/articles/3694780-auto-leveling), though I have no idea neither can I find any info how it is achieved.

Comment: Same as normalization.

Comment: Thanks. But Descript does have separate feature for peak or loudness normlisation. They are not the same thing I don't think? I have also read [here](https://medium.com/keypleezer-music-tech-blog/audio-compression-normalization-and-leveling-4ce3d1466f80).

Comment: Can I also ask how do I choose all the parameters (e.g. threshold, noise floor and so on) for compressor please?

Comment: See expanded answer, above..